# Heater and fan don't work at the same time but work fine independently!

Tags: hvac, heater, fans

[image]I am having a problem with my Frigidaire heater and fan. When the heater starts working fan stops and vice versa. they both work fine independently but not at the same time. It happened after I installed an Ecobee thermostat. I switch back to the old thermostat but the issue still exists.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring diagram for your furnace please?

Comment: Can you also get us better closeups of the wiring at the furnace's thermostat terminal block (on the control board) and the various junctions involved as well please?

Comment: I think I found what the problem is! I short wired the pressure switch and it seems to be working fine. i am going to replace the pressure switch and hopefully it will work. Please let me know if you think otherwise